# By which factor does b increase if a is multiplied with 2?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

Consider
$$2a^2 = 3b^3.$$

By which factor does b increase if a is multiplied by 2?

Answer is 4. Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: Are you sure you copied the question correctly? The answer to the question as written above is not $4$.

Answer (score 1):

$$2a^2=3b^3$$
$$2(2a)^2 = 3(kb)^3$$
Solve for $k$.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, $b=b_0=\frac{2}{3}a^{2/3}$. If $a \to 2a$ then $3b^3=2(2a)^2=4 \cdot 2a^2 \implies b=4^{1/3} \cdot b_0$. So the answer it's not exactly 4 but $4^{1/3}$.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. It should be exactly 4 according to the answer sheet

Comment: Then the answer sheet is wrong. Consider the case $a=1$, then $b=(2/3)^{1/3}$ and when $a=2$, $b=(8/3)^{1/3}$. **$b^3$ increases a factor 4** but b doesn't.

Comment: Perhaps the question is copied incorrectly.